# Recursive function inside a require.js module

Tags: javascript, recursion, requirejs

I just started with require.js today. I was planning to create module and have sucessfully created one.

Now I want to make a recursive call to a return function in the module. How to do that?

My module.

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore'], function ($, _) {

    var thisModule = this;
    return {
        moduleFuntion: function (data) {
            //Code
            ...
            //How to call moduleFunction here.
        }
    }

});
```

I have tried

```
modelFunction();
```

and

```
thisModule.moduleFuntion();
```

I think splitting the code into another function rather than the return function and caling that recursively works

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore'], function ($, _) {

    var thisModule = this;
    function codeFunction(data) {
      //Code
      ....
      codeFunction()
    }
    return {
        moduleFuntion: function (data) {
            codeFunction(data);
        }
    }

});
```

But instead of that is that possible in my current code?

**Update** :

I have solved issue by

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore'], function ($, _) {

    return {
        moduleFuntion: function (data) {
            //Code
            ...
            var moduleObject = require('jsonviewer');
            moduleObject.moduleFuntion(dataNew);
        }
    }

});
```

Is this this the correct approach?

Note: I'm new to require so I would like to get experts opinion on the path I took

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually,

```
this.moduleFuntion();
```

should do the trick.

```
var thisModule = this;
```

Doesn't work since you are assigning the variable outside of the object you are returning, and thereby this isn't pointing to the object.

Here is a very simple example: [http://jsfiddle.net/ePV2Q/](http://jsfiddle.net/ePV2Q/1)

Comment: As I mentioned in the question I have tried that `thisModule.moduleFuntion();' where `var thisModule = this;`

Comment: Since you are assigning the thisModule variable outside of your object, it doesn't point to the object scope, but to the scope your module is in.

Answer (score 0):

I'd reccomend reading up on [named function expressions](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/).

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore'], function ($, _) {

    var thisModule = this;
    return {
        moduleFuntion: function moduleFunc(data) { // give this function expression a name
            //Code
            ...
            //How to call moduleFunction here.
                // Now you can call moduleFunction using moduleFunc:
                moduleFunc(...);
        }
    }

});
```